# Unable to set Collection Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to set Collection cell. One is always center. And Other Two left Corner of Collection View. And I want to know indexpath of Center Item. Initially When a data load First cell is always on Center. Please See Image.
[image]

Here is my try but not get Success. Please Help me or Suggest Any Another Way.

```
   extension AudioViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }

        // make a cell for each cell index path
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            // get a reference to our storyboard cell
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AudioCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AudioCollectionViewCell

 cell.backgeoundImage.image = UIImage(named :"play.png")

            return cell
        }

 *

    @objc(collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:)  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 0)
        }

*
```

Comment: What is your current result? It's unclear, because we don't know the size of the cells (did you override the corresponding layout delegate method?), and if it's for the center, you should implement the didScroll (or something similar) method that will give you the current scroll offset (and then, calculate by simple logic which one is on front), and there are questions also about giving a small deceleration animation during the "paging".

Comment: @Larme PLease Help me some code Snippets

Comment: Even easier: use `indexPathsForVisibleItems` and calculate the median value!